# SQL Server: delete rows which does not have a parent (based on 2 columns join)

Tags: sql, sql-delete, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2014-express

I am trying to delete entries from child table (accidents) which have not parent (location). If I understand correctly, I cannot have these rows in case I want to create a relationship between these two tables (**one to one/many** instead of **one/zero to one/many** which I have now). The foreign key is a combination of fk_veld5 and jaar. This is how I tried to tackle it:

```
DELETE FROM accidents 
WHERE FK_veld5 IN 
  (SELECT fk_veld5, Jaar_vkl FROM accidents
   EXCEPT SELECT FK_VELD5, JAAR FROM locations) 
 AND Jaar_vkl IN
  (SELECT fk_veld5, Jaar_vkl FROM accidents
   EXCEPT Select FK_VELD5, JAAR FROM locations)
GO
```

Selections in brackets contain fk_veld5 and Jaar_vkl from rows which I want to delete (I do not succeeded in selecting full rows which I want to delete).

After running the query above I am getting this error:

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 24 Only one expression can be
>   specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with
>   EXISTS.

I also tried to use EXISTS but it did not work.

I was trying to find a solution but every attempt ended with an error. Can you please answer me if what I want to do is possible? Or should I use LEFT JOIN to select all accidents which have the location and save them to new table which in the end will replace the old accidents table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is not correct, the sub select should only return one column when you use IN caluse

Try this

```
;with cte as
(
   SELECT fk_veld5, Jaar_vkl FROM accidents
   EXCEPT 
   Select FK_VELD5, JAAR FROM locations
)
DELETE a FROM accidents a
INNER JOIN CTE B on a.FK_veld5 = b.FK_veld5 and a.Jaar_vkl = b.Jaar_vkl
```

Comment: thank you for an advise and the solution. I have already tried the one from Dmytro Shevchenko and it worked so I cannot try yours but I am sure it would work as well. It was smart to join the selection from brackets with the accident table to delete the rows which match. I could think about it ;).

Comment: I've tried your solution on another table and it worked. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE
  accidents
FROM
  accidents AS a
LEFT JOIN
  locations AS l
  ON a.fk_veld5 = l.FK_VELD5
  AND a.Jaar_vkl = l.JAAR
WHERE
  l.FK_VELD5 IS NULL
```